# ORA-01652: gaining an understanding of tablespace and datafiles

Tags: oracle

I've looked at other posts ([1](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/132253/ora-01652-unable-to-extend-temp-segment-by-128-in-tablespace-hfdora-temp))([2](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75632/how-can-i-resolve-this-ora-01652-error-when-i-already-added-a-new-file-to-the-te)) around this error, but what I don't understand is where certain objects are located. I am unsure about where the tablespace (TEMP in my case) is exactly, and where the datafile that is added to it to extend its size would be located.

In several posts, I saw a file path for the datafile, but I don't understand where that's stored. To give some details, I am on macOS, and connecting to an Oracle database by using a bridge. Where would this datafile go in my case?

I've had a look at resources like [this](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Tablespace#Temp_tablespaces), but I am not the admin for the database I am using, and I am not sure what the equivalent tables are named in my database. How can I find out?

Comment: if you post here then please always add the exact error message.Contact an  admin of the database and show the error message

Comment: `select * from dba_data_files` will show you the location of the tablespace files (on the database **server**)

Comment: What do you mean by "connecting to an Oracle database by using a bridge"?  You are on a computer (a Mac?) and the database is on another computer (of unknown OS?).  The data file is stored on the server that runs the database.  So an ora-1652 says "unable to extend a temp segment" in some tablespace.  Not necessarily the TEMP ts.  Hate to be "unhelpful" but if you are not the DBA ("but I am not the admin for the database I am using") then this really isn't your problem to solve.  You need to be talking to the DBA who _is_ responsible.

Comment: Thanks, EdStevens, I was just trying to gain a conceptual understanding of what was going on. I am not the DBA or admin, and I think it's more likely that the error is because "creating too many joins" as I've read in other places.